# HttpResponseMessage returns 403 in .NET

Tags: python, c#, async-await, httpresponse, dotnet-httpclient

I have a `async` method which make a `HttpClient` call repeatedly in `.Net`. I simulate my code as a small console app below:

```
    private static HttpClient req { get; set; } = new HttpClient();

    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please press enter to start healthCheck");
        Console.ReadLine();

        healthCheck();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static async Task healthCheck()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            req.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("apikey", "myPassword");

            string strUrl = "http://myUrl";

            HttpResponseMessage hrm = await req.GetAsync(strUrl);

            Console.WriteLine("=> statusCode:" + (int)hrm.StatusCode);

            await Task.Delay(5000);
        }
    }
```

The output is:

[image]

The problem is when I use `Postman` or write this code with `python` as below, every time it responded `200` instead of `403`.

```
import requests as req
import time as t

url = "http://adpsms.adpdigital.com/report/?date=2021-08-30"
customHeader = {"apikey": "sssrjdIiGisbViKA"}

i = 10

while (i > 0):
    response = req.get(url, headers = customHeader)

    print("statusCode: " + str(response.status_code))

    i -= 1
    t.sleep(5)
```

[image]

I supposed it is a server error but when I responded `200` every time with `python` I understand it would be a problem with my code or something client based.

Since my project is based on `.NET` I want to make it work on it.
Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Try to add DefaultRequestHeader only once, when you creating HttpClient.
You don't need to add them on every iteration of your loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On every iteration of your loop, you are adding DefaultRequestHeaders.
It means that they will be added again and again on each iteration of your cycle to the global instance of HttpClient

According to [the official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.web.http.httpclient.defaultrequestheaders?view=winrt-20348) these headers will be sent with each request.
For your particular task you might add them only once(that's why the name contains prefix default.)

So if you slightly rewrite your code like this:

```
private static HttpClient req { get; set; } = new HttpClient();

    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please press enter to start healthCheck");
        Console.ReadLine();
        AddDefaultHeaders();
        healthCheck();
    
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    
    private static void AddDefaultHeaders()
    {
        req.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("apiKey", "myPassword");
    }

    private static async Task healthCheck()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            string strUrl = "http://myUrl";
    
            HttpResponseMessage hrm = await req.GetAsync(strUrl);
    
            Console.WriteLine("=> statusCode:" + (int)hrm.StatusCode);
    
            await Task.Delay(5000);
        }
    }
```

It should works fine.

Comment: Thanks a lot man! I didn't notice that unfortunately. You helped a lot I was stuck for hours! Good Luck.

Comment: @dev.amirali, you're welcome!Have a nice day, and less bugs)